# ZipCode Loses Formatting When Using Macro to Save-As CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, formatting

I have an excel macro that converts data into a specific format and then saves a copy of a specific tab as CSV for upload into a webportal. When saving to CSV, the zipcode formatting is being lost. When I preview the CSV in file explorer the leading zero is there, and I have the below code to maintain the leading zero. However, when the file is opened it drops which I believe is causing issue when we are trying to upload the CSV into the portal. When I manually open the CSV and do special formatting->zip code & save there is no issue uploading the file.

Is there another way to code the zipcode formatting to ensure it isnt lost when saving as a CSV using VBA?

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH:AH").NumberFormat = "00000"
```

Comment: Number formats to do not get passed to csv.  You need to format the value itself, by looping the range and use: `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH"&i).Value = Format(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH"&i).Value,"00000")` where `i` is the row variable.

Comment: But that will not change, that if you open the csv again after saving Excel will remove the leading `0`.  As stated csv do not retain cell formatting and Excel will try to convert what ever is there to what it "thinks" it should be.

Comment: Actually, number formats can be passed to CSV. Try using ```Range.Text``` instead of ```Range.Value``` to read the ZipCodes to be written to CSV. ```Range.Text``` pulls the text displayed in a cell, with leading zeros, instead of the underlying value. But that might not be the problem here. It sounds like the zero is being dropped when the CSV is reopened in Excel ("When I preview the CSV in file explorer the leading zero is there"). If that's the case the issue is downstream from writing the CSV, and ```Range.Text``` won't help.

Comment: On further reflection... It sounds like you're saving the tab to CSV. Can you write the CSV file directly from VBA, using the ```Range.Text``` statement? If you let Excel create the CSV from the tab, @Scott Craner is correct, Excel will throw away the formatting when it saves the tab as CSV. Writing the file yourself is an extra step or two, but VBA can write a text file easily, and if it retains the leading zeros it's worth the effort.

Comment: Agree with the above users, sounds like your CSV file is being saved correctly at first, but then reformatted incorrectly if you open it again Excel (Excel will format as number and remove leading 0's automatically). If you need to open the CSV file to check or change the data, right-click the CSV file > Edit, it should open in Notepad, and it won't change the format / leading 0's.

Comment: If the zip code is properly formatted when you open the csv file in NotePad or other text editor, then the csv file is correct. The problem has to do with "***upload the CSV into the portal.*** Whatever method you are using for this step is interpreting the zip code as a number. You need to ensure this step interprets the zip code field as text. (If you want to see it in Excel, you can use one of the import wizards, and define that column as text).